# How to implement custom boolean widget for use with QDataWidgetMapper?

Tags: qt, user-interface, model-view-controller

What do I have to implement to make my own boolean widget for use with QDataWidgetMapper?

I have created a USER property that the mapper is, to my understanding, supposed to use.

The interaction with the database via QSqlTableModel using the (same) QDataWidgetMapper works with qt's own widgets, but does not seem to work with this widget I created.

Even though the widget works and displays database data, changing widget value does not change the value in the database. [correction: data from database is read to the widget state ok.]

Current header file:

```
#ifndef COMPENSATIONCONTROLCHECKABLE_H
#define COMPENSATIONCONTROLCHECKABLE_H
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class CompensationControlCheckable;
}

class CompensationControlCheckable : public QAbstractButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool checked READ isChecked WRITE setChecked NOTIFY compensationChanged USER true )

public:
    explicit CompensationControlCheckable(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CompensationControlCheckable();
    void setChecked(bool checkd);
    const bool isChecked() const;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e);

private slots:
    void on_startCompensation_clicked();

    void on_cancelCompensation_clicked();
signals:
    void compensationChanged(bool);
    void checked(bool);
private:
    bool checkedValue;
    Ui::CompensationControlCheckable *ui;
};

#endif // COMPENSATIONCONTROLCHECKABLE_H
```

Version 2, now I have removed checked overrides and instead call the QAbstractButton setChecked and isChecked in setCompensation and isCompensation, respectively. The constructor calls setCheckable(true);. This works exactly as above; reading from db ok, writing to db does not work:

```
#ifndef COMPENSATIONCONTROLCHECKABLE_H
#define COMPENSATIONCONTROLCHECKABLE_H
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class CompensationControlCheckable;
}

class CompensationControlCheckable : public QAbstractButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool compensation READ isCompensation WRITE setCompensation NOTIFY compensationChanged USER true )

public:
    explicit CompensationControlCheckable(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CompensationControlCheckable();
    void setCompensation(bool checkd);
    bool isCompensation() const;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e);

private slots:
    void on_startCompensation_clicked();
    void on_cancelCompensation_clicked();
signals:
    void compensationChanged(bool);
private:
    bool compensationValue;
    Ui::CompensationControlCheckable *ui;
};

#endif // COMPENSATIONCONTROLCHECKABLE_H
```

Answer (score 1):

`QDataWidgetMapper` prefers to use the property with `USER true` for its mapping but there already [one called checked in `QAbstractButton`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) use that property instead. You may need to call `isCheckable(true)` in the constructor;

Comment: The 5.3 documentation for QDataWidgetMapper says the following so the USER property I have above should be ok? Where did you get the `value` property idea from?

"By default, each widget's user property is used to transfer data between the model and the widget. Since Qt 4.3, an additional addMapping() function enables a named property to be used instead of the default user property."

Comment: indeed: looking again `QAbstractButton` already has a user property called checked

Comment: So umh, what are you saying in the end? That my above example should work? (Q updated, actually it reads from db ok, just does not write to db)

Comment: you should remove all checked related stuff from the header (and implementations from `CompensationControlCheckable` but instead use the same methods from `QAbstractButton`

Comment: Added the new version in the original question, doesn't work any better though.